# SQL Update with CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I'm going to use example tables.

tblAnimal:

```
---------------------------------
|Animal    | Colour |  Gender   |
---------------------------------
|Dog       |        |           |
---------------------------------
```

tblDescription:

```
-------------------------------
| Animal |  ID  | Description |
-------------------------------
|  Dog   |   1  |    Male     |
-------------------------------
|  Dog   |  92  |   White     |
-------------------------------
```

So I want to update tblAnimal so that the Colour and Gender are populated.

I used the code

```
UPDATE tblAnimal
SET Colour = CASE WHEN tblDescription.ID = 92 THEN tblDescription.Description END,
    Gender = CASE WHEN tblDescription.ID = 1 THEN tblDescription.Description END
FROM tblDescription INNER JOIN tblAnimal 
    ON tblDescription.Animal = tblAnimal.Animal
```

But it isn't working. Both columns in tblAnimal remains NULL. It seems like SQL Server only checks the first row in tblDescription.

How would I write this UPDATE statement so that both Colour and Gender are what is in tblDescription?

**EDIT**

Thank you all for your solutions! And yes the table needs to be normalized, but this is strictly for example to go along with my question on the UPDATE statement.

Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Create table tblDescription(
Animal varchar(20),
ID int,
Description varchar(20)
)

Insert into tblAnimal(Animal)
values ('Dog')

Insert into tblDescription
Select 'Dog',1,'Male' union all
Select 'Dog',92,'White'

Select * from tblAnimal

Select * from tblDescription

---Update

Update a
SET Colour = (Select d.description from tbldescription d where d.id =92),
Gender = (Select d.description from tbldescription d where d.id =1)

From tblAnimal a inner join
tblDescription d on d.Animal =a.Animal
```

NOTE:
    This will work but what would i do is normalization of tbldescription.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
UPDATE tblAnimal a
SET
    a.Colour = (SELECT d.Description d FROM tblDescription d WHERE d.Animal = a.Animal AND ID = 92),
    a.Gender = (SELECT d.Description d FROM tblDescription d WHERE d.Animal = a.Animal AND ID = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
UPDATE tblAnimal
    SET colour = (select  Description from  tblDescription where ID = 92),
        Gender = (select  Description from  tblDescription where ID = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a ID reference in tblAnimal in order to get correlation with tblDescription.

tblAnimal:

```
---------------------------------
|Animal | ID   | Colour |  Gender|
---------------------------------
|Dog    |  1  |         |       |
---------------------------------
|Dog    |  92 |         |       |
---------------------------------
```

Then you could run this:

```
UPDATE 
  tblAnimal as a
SET
  Colour = (SELECT Description from tblDescription x WHERE x.id = a.id),
  Gender = (SELECT Description FROM tblDescription x WHERE x.id = a.id)
```

Comment: Probably I couldn't understand the problem. My answer assumed a one-to-one relationship between tables. It is probable that @rida-benhammane 's answer is the correct one.

Comment: ***@go_55699***, Here is the [***SQL Fiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/579a1/1/2) that shows that this approach does indeed work.